# Inserting combo box values?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get my system to insert combo box values into my access database. I always get this very long error whenever I try to click my 'add' button and I somehow get this feeling that it's because of my INSERT statement. This is my whole code for my form. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class AdmMain


    Sub fillcombo()
        strsql = " select yrgr from yearandgrade"
        Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acscmd.Connection = acsconn
        acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

        While (acsdr.Read())
            cboyr.Items.Add(acsdr("yrgr"))
        End While
        acscmd.Dispose()
        acsdr.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub comb2()
        strsql = " select sections from sectio"
        Dim acscmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        acscmd.CommandText = strsql
        acscmd.Connection = acsconn
        acsdr = acscmd.ExecuteReader

        While (acsdr.Read())
            cbosec.Items.Add(acsdr("sections"))
        End While
        acscmd.Dispose()
        acsdr.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to logout?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged out of VCM's Library Information System!", "Logout Confirmed")
            Me.Close()
            LoginUser.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.txtFName.Text = ""
        Me.txtMName.Text = ""
        Me.txtLName.Text = ""
        Me.cboyr.Text = ""
        Me.cbosec.Text = ""
        Me.txtFName.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AdmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Module1.connect()
        Me.fillcombo()
        Me.comb2()

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim rbdtext As String = cboyr.SelectedItem.ToString
        Dim uno As String = cbosec.SelectedItem.ToString
        Try
            Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"
                conn.Open()
                Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO students (StudentID, FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Yr, Section) " & _
                                        "VALUES (@studid, @fname,@mname,@lname,@yr, @sec)"
                Dim SqlCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studid", TxtID.Text)
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName.Text)
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtMName.Text)
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLName.Text)
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", rbdtext)
                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", uno)
                SqlCommand.Connection = conn

                Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

                MsgBox("One record successfully added!", "Added!")

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

**Heres the error the keeps showing btw!**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lgah.png

Comment: Use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader (well if you set the command it works also with ExecuteReader but there is no point in getting back a reader when you INSERT a record)

Comment: "Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery" I get a blue line below Sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery. "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader'."

Comment: Exactly. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows that your command (a non SELECT command) has changed, inserted, deleted. An insert statement doesn't return any reader because there is nothing to read, just the number of rows inserted (it should be 1 for your query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query in this way

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim rbdtext As String = cboyr.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim uno As String = cbosec.SelectedItem.ToString

    Try
        Dim cnString = = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _ 
                         "Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"
        Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO students " & _
            "(StudentID, FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Yr, [Section]) " & _
            "VALUES (@studid, @fname,@mname,@lname,@yr, @sec)"

        ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
        ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

        Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
        Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn)

            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studid", TxtID.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtMName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", rbdtext)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", uno)

            Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            if rowsInserted > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("One record successfully added!", "Added!")
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Failure to add new record!", "Failure!")
            End if
        End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I have changed the name of your OleDbCommand object to avoid unnecessary confusion with the class SqlCommand used in SqlClient namespace (Not strictly necessary but nevertheless confusing when reading your code). Then I have used the OleDbCommand constructor that gets both the command text and the connection to be used by your command. This avoids to forget setting these essential properties, finally **SECTION** is a [reserved keyword for MS-Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), thus, when used in query text, you need to encapsulate it between square brackets otherwise you get a `SYNTAX ERROR`

Comment: It still gives me an error http://i.imgur.com/h46l5Ec.png? Thanks for the valuable reply!@Steve

Comment: This seems to happen in the call to MsgBox. Try to use the NET Framework [MessageBox.Show method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) and not the VB6 compatibility one. Updating the answer now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are never assigning a select statement to `SqlCommand` inside your `btnAdd_Click` method.  Try adding `SqlCommand.CommandText = sqlquery`.

Comment: I tried adding SqlCommand.CommandText = sqlquery. but another error came up when I ran my program. Something like Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @Phonseal  -- "Something like"?  How can we possibly help you figure it out if you're being so vague?  Please include the entire text of the error.